# your better life

Tags: possessives, comparative

Can one say:

> When he sees your better life, he will be jealous.

Instead of:

> When he sees your life, which is better than his, he will be jealous.

Can one say:

> When he sees your better house, he will be jealous.

Instead of:

> When he sees your house, which is better than his, he will be jealous.

Many thanks.

Comment: My feeling is that it's grammatically correct but not fluent.  *your better life* is not the same as "your life, which is better than his" because *your better life* doesn't state what the life is better than.  Better than his?  Better than it was before?  Better than some other standard?

Answer (score 1):

You can say this but to be really clear you must first establish a context of comparing, otherwise it will catch the listener/reader off guard a little bit.

The second sentence is better if previous conversation wasn't talking about the quality of the lives.

> You have all these things that make your life good, and he doesn't have these things.  When he sees your better life, he will be jealous.